# Which RigVedic deities have a parentage in the RigVeda itself?

Tags: rig-veda, genealogy

Later scriptures have given geneologies to RigVedic deities who have no parentage in the RigVeda.  I am asking about one rigVedic deity giving birth to another.

Comment: Interesting and excellent question.

Answer (score 2):

Indra, Agni, Vayu, Chandra and Surya were born from the body of Virata.

> **Rigveda 10:90:13.** The **Moon** was gendered from his mind, and from his eye the **Sun** had birth; **Indra** and **Agni** from his mouth were born, and **Vayu** from his breath.

In Rigveda 1:164:33 Indra is said to be born from Dyuas and Prithvi.

Dyaus is my Father, my begetter: kinship is here. This great earth is my kin and Mother.Between the wide-spread world-halves is the birth-place: the Father laid the Daughter's germ within it.Rigved 1;164:33

> Rigveda 4:17:4 Thy Father Dyaus esteemed himself a hero: most noble was the work of Indra's Maker, His who begat the strong bolt's Lord who roareth, immovable like earth from her foundation.